Projective chain complexes are flat.
I am following the note Cohomological Class Field Theory by Sam Raskin.
We always work for $R$-modules. A (maybe unbounded) chain complex $P$ is called projective (K-projective, homotopy projective) if for any acyclic chain complex $A$, the (internal) Hom complex $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(P,A)$ is acyclic. A chain complex $F$ of left $R$-modules is called flat if for any acyclic chain complex $A$ of right $R$-modules, the complex $A \otimes F$ is acyclic.
In notes lecture $13$, there is a Claim that any projective complex is flat. Here are my questions:

Are there any discriptions of projective and flat chain complexes, for example, explicitly on the level of modules and differentials?

How are projective chain complexes related to the projective objects in the category of chain complexes? (is it related to some model structure or something?)

How to prove the claim that any projective chain complex is flat?


Remark. For some references, see stacks project and Resolutions of unbounded complexes by N. Spaltenstein. See also here.
For some model structures on the category of chain complexes, see nlab.

Are you familiar with the material in, say, Weibel's An introduction to homological algebra?

@ZhenLin: Yes, I am familiar with basic homological algebra (and commutative algebra).

It is difficult to describe all K-projective chain complexes.
However, it is known that a bounded below chain complex of projective modules is K-projective.
This is often proved as a lemma when constructing the derived category; for example, it is a simple corollary of Corollary 10.4.7 in [Weibel, An introduction to homological algebra], and it is explicitly stated here in Stacks.
As it happens, bounded below chain complexes of projective modules are also cofibrant in the projective model structure on chain complexes, but it is also difficult to describe all cofibrant objects.
Despite the above, K-projective chain complexes are otherwise unrelated to projective objects in the abelian category of chain complexes.
(A chain complex is a projective object if and only if it is a split-exact chain complex of projective modules.)
Notice that the class of K-projective chain complexes is closed under homotopy equivalence, whereas the class of projective objects is not.
A K-projective chain complex that is also degreewise projective is said to be dg-projective.
The claim that any K-projective chain complex is K-flat is basically just abstract nonsense.
The functors $\otimes$ and $\textrm{Hom}$ are adjoint in the category of chain complexes:
$$\textrm{Hom} (A \otimes B, C) \cong \textrm{Hom} (A, \textrm{Hom} (B, C))$$
If $B$ is an acyclic chain complex of left modules and $C$ is a K-injective chain complex of abelian groups, then $\textrm{Hom} (B, C)$ is an acyclic chain complex of right modules.
If, furthermore, $A$ is a K-projective chain complex of right modules, then $\textrm{Hom} (A, \textrm{Hom} (B, C))$ is an acyclic chain complex of abelian groups.
But if $\textrm{Hom} (A \otimes B, C)$ is acyclic for all K-injective chain complexes $C$, then $A \otimes B$ is also acyclic.
(This is because every chain complex is quasi-isomorphic to a K-injective chain complex.)
Hence, K-projective implies K-flat.

Oops, yes, right.
